# how to make Dropdown values as labels in database in php

Tags: php

Help me write PHP code for dropdown list value as labels in database and values for those labels taken from textbox each time.
If you have any idea about or related code please share

Comment: Stackoverflow isn't a place for people to write code for you. You need to try something yourself first and then post the code here when you get stuck on an issue and need help resolving it.

Comment: yaa  I tried I did not got exactly